# Multiple GSA Connector instances accessing the same Sharepoint Crawl

Tags: sharepoint, google-search-appliance

Google documentation makes the following recommendation :

> We recommend that you do not have two connector instances accessing the same SharePoint Crawl URL.
>
> https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/connectors/260/connector_admin/sharepoint_content_connector#confconanch

I am setting up a sandbox for our SharePoint connector, so I wanted to test the SharePoint connector against our production SharePoint. What is the impact of  two connector instances accessing the same SharePoint? Is it just additional load on SharePoint? Any ideas on possibly mitigating the load by confining the crawl to  a subset of the SharePoint, on one of the connector instances?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right! It is going to increase the load on Sharepoint. You may want to restrict the crawl patterns and setup crawler schedule to be different.